# Information inserts into database on every click. How do you prevent that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say if someone spam clicks a button, every click goes into the database and it's just a waste of space. How do I prevent that?

```
// when the user clicks on like
    $('.icon-appear').on('click', function(){
        var postid = $(this).data('id');
        $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_profiles.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'liked': 1,
                'postid': postid
            },
            success: function(response){
                $post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(response);
                $post.siblings().removeClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().removeClass('hide');

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just disable the click once a user has hit spam?

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: In your db have a uniqueness constraint ensuring a user can spam/like a post only once.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to add a "one time" event on an element.

```
//when the user clicks on like
    $('.icon-appear').one('click', function(){
        var postid = $(this).data('id');
        $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_profiles.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'liked': 1,
                'postid': postid
            },
            success: function(response){
                $post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(response);
                $post.siblings().removeClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().removeClass('hide');

            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can also remove the event handler within your callback using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/);

```
    $('.icon-appear').on('click', function(event){
        //All of your logic
        $(this).off( event );
});
```

Comment: This kinda worked, but then once I clicked again the number of likes weren't actively increase/decrease.